# How to prevent the following regex to match things between two ( )s?

Tags: regex, vim

This regex:

```
\v\(.*\)\ze\s\-\>
```

Matches this (including the parenthesis):

```
functionDefinition = (matchedArgs) ->
```

Everything OK. The problem arises here:

```
$(window).on "scroll", (e) ->
```

The `(char)` aren't matched individually but together, like this:

```
$<<(window).on "scroll", (e)>> ->
```

How can I fix the regex so that they are matched individually? Like this:

```
$<<(window)>>.on "scroll", <<(e)>> ->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change it to the following:

```
\v\(.{-}\)\ze\W
```

It does a non-greedy match `.{-}` between parentheses followed by any non-letter character `\W`.

---

**UPDATE**

I thought you wanted to match also first pair of parens. Use this one instead:

```
\v\([^)]*\)\ze\s-\>
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** For explanation

Of course: `\v` means very magic so it avoids to escape many especial characters like parentheses, curly braces and so on. This `\([^)]*\)` matches some content between parentheses in non-greedy mode. `\ze\s-\>` is a zero-width assertion with content that follows but without matching.

Comment: Oh thanks that almost make it. But I only want the `( )`s that have a `->` in front to be matched.

Comment: @alexchenco: I've updated the answer again to add an explanation.